# Any known Orchard CMS case studies?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, orchardcms, oxite

We're looking into using Orchard CMS for a project. I know the CMS hasn't been around for a long time, but I was wondering if there were any known high profile and successful case studies using Orchard CMS or its predecessor Oxite?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The recently released Orchard Gallery is itself built using Orchard: http://orchardproject.net/gallery. Also, the NuGet gallery website is using the exact same code as the Orchard Gallery, with a different theme applied: http://nuget.org. What's more, the Orchard/NuGet gallery is mostly implemented as a custom Orchard module, and that code is open source. Check out http://orchardgallery.codeplex.com for more details.

Comment: NuGet does not use Orchard anymore (http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/12/06/what-s-the-deal-with-orchard-and-nuget-does-orchard-suck.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Bath Spa implemented Orchard for both their registration and housing booking systems.

- http://registration.bathspa.ac.uk
- http://housing.bathspa.ac.uk

I think they are also due to roll out the external site in Orchard too at some point.

Granted the sites are not 'high profile' in techie circles, but for a poly tech university in the UK to adopt open source, that's quite a big thing for them.

Answer (score 3):

You can find lots of examples of websites using Orchard on [Show Orchard](http://showorchard.com). Featured websites come with interviews of the developers.

Comment: The site is down.  does not work.  any estimated time frame on when it will be up?

Answer (score 2):

We have just finished building http://www.oxfordeconomics.com/ with Orchard CMS. This is both a marketing and subscription content site which receives on average 1000 visitors and 4000+ page views daily. It operates in a niche business area and is not a consumer site.

There were a number of challenges regarding caching, performance of taxonomies, widget management to name a few. Orchard's architecture is very flexible, but there's obviously a learning curve. I'm happy to discuss more details at http://sophilabs.com (contact)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's extremely early for that as far as Orchard is concerned. There are a few sites using it but nothing "high-profile". Nor should there be at this point.
It's a little different for Oxite, which has been running some pretty high profile sites such as the Mix site and others around the people doing Channel 9. It hasn't been made into a case study that I know of though.

Answer (score 1):

The MIX11 site was built on Orchard: http://live.visitmix.com/news/mix11-adopts-orchard.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check video tutorials , that could be found on http://pluralsight.com/